# Mi mapa sigue vacio despues de llenarlo con un JSON

Tags: javascript, json, map

Mi problema es que creo un nuevo mapa donde la clave es el codigo de un estudiante(int) y su valor sera un objeto el cual tendra el nombre del estudiante y un arreglo de notas, ejemplo:

```js
const eMap = new Map();
const cnt = document.getElementById("conte");
var descrip = [];


async function leerJSON(url) {
    try {
        let response = await fetch(url);
        let user = await response.json();
        return user;
    } catch (err) {
        alert(err);
    }
}


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",  ()=> {
    let url = "https://programacion-web---i-sem-2019.gitlab.io/persistencia/json_web/json/estudiantes.json";
    leerJSON(url).then(
        datos => {
            for (let i = 0; i < datos.estudiantes.length; i++) {
                let E = datos.estudiantes[i];
                var obj = {
                    name: E.nombre,
                    notas: E.notas
                };
                eMap.set(E.codigo, obj);
            }
            descrip = datos.descripcion;
        }
    );
    /*El problema esta aqui ya que al acceder a eMap.get(115100).notas me arroja el error: "cannot
     read property 'notas' of undefined at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> */
    cnt.innerHTML = eMap.get(115100).notas;
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero luego al accecer al mapa con esa misma desde la consola en el navegador me dice que si esta el objeto ahi almacenado, no se que pueda estar pasando.
¿Cual podria ser el error? o ¿Que deberia hacer para no acceder a undefined?

Comment: Tu error esta aquí `const eMap = new Map();`. Estas declarando una constante, por lo tanto su valor inicial nunca va a cambiar. Trata de declarar la variable como `var` o `let`.

Comment: he intentado eso, pero tampoco funciono:(

Comment: ¿Podrías expandir (desde la consola) y agregar a tu pregunta lo que contiene alguno de los estudiantes?

Answer (score 1):

Al momento de acceder a eMap.get(key) estaba haciendo la peticion antes de que el mapa se llenara,  debido a que este se llena en una funcion asincrona, la solucion fue acceder al map dentro de la funcion then